# Magento can not list customers

Tags: python, magento

I tried the following code. Other APIs are working, only the customerCustomerList is not working..

```
def main():
    client = SOAPpy.WSDL.Proxy(WSDL_ADDR)
    sid = client.login(username=USERNAME,apiKey=APIKEY)
    print 'Logined as session id %s' % sid

    print 'Listing customers...'
    res = client.customerCustomerList(sid)
    print res

    client.endSession(sessionId=sid)
```

And it gives the following exception:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SOAPpy/Client.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kw)
    545                     return self.__f_call(*args, **kw)
    546             else:
--> 547                 return self.__r_call(*args, **kw)
    548
    549         def __getattr__(self, name):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SOAPpy/Client.pyc in __r_call(self, *args, **kw)
    567         def __r_call(self, *args, **kw):
    568             return self.__call(self.__name, args, kw, self.__ns, self.__sa,
--> 569                 self.__hd, self.__ma)
    570
    571         def __repr__(self):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SOAPpy/Client.pyc in __call(self, name, args, kw, ns, sa, hd, ma)
    469
    470
--> 471         p, attrs = parseSOAPRPC(r, attrs = 1)
    472
    473         try:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SOAPpy/Parser.pyc in parseSOAPRPC(xml_str, header, body, attrs, rules, ignore_ext)
   1103 def parseSOAPRPC(xml_str, header = 0, body = 0, attrs = 0, rules = None, ignore_ext=None):
   1104
-> 1105     t = _parseSOAP(xml_str, rules = rules, ignore_ext=ignore_ext)
   1106     p = t.body[0]
   1107

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SOAPpy/Parser.pyc in _parseSOAP(xml_str, rules, ignore_ext, forbid_entities, forbid_external, forbid_dtd)
   1086         parser._parser = None
   1087         print traceback.format_exc()
-> 1088         raise e
   1089
   1090     return t

SAXParseException: <unknown>:1:0: no element found
```

I tried to cut down the amount of data to return by using filters, but it did not work neither.

```
    res = client.customerCustomerList(sid,{
            'group_id':'1',
            'store_id':'1'
        })
```

customerCustomerList() is in the WSDL, so it may not be a permission problem.

My current work-around is to enumerate customerIDs and fetch them one-by-one, which is far from ideal...

```
print 'Listing all the customers...'
for i in xrange(0,999999):
    try:
        res = client.customerCustomerInfo(sid,str(i))
        print res
    except Exception ,ex:
        sys.stderr.write( str(ex)+'\n')
```

Comment: This endpoint seems to be available only in v2 SOAP (http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/customer/customer.list.html) what is your `WSDL_ADDR` ?

Comment: @Niloct WSDL_ADDR is http://www.gluestore.com.au/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1, I am pretty sure the endpoint is in the WSDL

Comment: Ok, and Magento version is ?

Comment: @Niloct I don't know the version it's using. It's a client's website. I've sent email to request more info from their support.

Comment: @Niloct The Magento Connect Manager version is 1.12.0.1, don't know if it helps

Comment: Have you tried this: http://www.soapclient.com/soaptest.html ? In the method of listing customers, there are more parameters being listed, do you know why ?

Comment: @Niloct According to this documentation (http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/customer/customer.list.html), parameters except sessionID is optional. I tried to used SoapUI to invoke the API, the connections just timeouts after a few minutes, and SoapUI did not show anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway I get the code working by applying Filters to fetch a subset of records at a time. Magento API really should provide pagination.

It would not work using `SOAPpy`, anyway, the code worked using `suds`

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
from suds.client import Client

client = Client(MAGENTO_WSDL_ADDRESS)
sid = client.service.login(username=USER_NAME, apiKey=API_KEY)

# Fetch all new users in last 24 hours
filter = {  
    "complex_filter":{  
        "item":{  
            "key":"created_at",
            "value":{  
                "key":"from",
                "value": datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=24), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            }
        }
    }
}

res = client.services.customerCustomerList(sid, filters=filter)

# New customer ids from last 24 hours.
new_uids = [x.customer_id for x in res]
```

Answer (score 0):

'SAXParseException: :1:0: no element found' issue mean what server return some answer but not in XML format.

Instead of:

```
res = client.customerCustomerList(sid)
```

try this:

```
res = client.customerCustomerList(sid, None)
```

or this:

```
complex_filter = [{'complex_filter': [{
    'key': 'customer_id',
    'value': [{
        'key': 'gt',
        'value': 0}]
    }]
}]
res = client.customerCustomerList(sid, complex_filter)
```